# Why IUSR does not have any permission on wwwroot

Tags: iis, permissions, application-pools, iis-8.5, iusr

I'm trying to understand IIS 8.5 user account model.

**IUSR:** default anonymous user (can be changed). it is the identity which request the web resource

**ApplicationPoolIdentity:** a special identity used for app pools

**IIS_IUSRS:** it is a group where all special ApplicationPoolIdentity are in

IIS_IUSRS has read/execute permission on wwwroot folder

I don't get why IUSR does not have any permission on wwwroot folder

How could any web request not result in a 401???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the default permission for `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`:

```
BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS:(RX)
BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(I)(F)
NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
CREATOR OWNER:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
```

you can see the the `Users` group has read access, **IUSR** is automatically a member of the `Users` group, that's why it can access the files.

If you remove the permissions for `Users` you should get a `401.3`

Comment: For some reason I had incorrectly remembered the IUSR being part of the guests group, how odd...

Answer (score 1):

Because the `IUSR` account is put in the `users` group by virtue of the `NT Authority\Authenticated Users` group.

Mostly these two exist for legacy reasons, but serve two distinct purposes.

- The `IUSR` account is used for anonymous authentication
- The `IIS_IUSRS` group is used to allow for security control for application pool users

There are some [write-ups on the history](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis) and some decent [information on the usage of the IUSR account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981949) and it's predecessor the [IUSR_computername](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/anonymous-authentication-iusr-account.html) available.

Comment: The Adobe document in your second link actually talks about `IUSR_computername` not `IUSR` which is a different beast and doesn't exist in IIS7+

Comment: @PeterHahndorf Thx, only skimmed the articles. Fixed.